# How to use the ampersand as part of HTML in shiny?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I would like to use the HTML character reference `&nbsp;` in my shiny app. However, for examples,

`tags$div("aaa&nbsp;bbb")` in R will render

`<div>aaa&amp;nbsp;bbb</div>` in HTML.

Therefore, while I am expecting

> aaa bbb

to be displayed, what I get is instead

> aaa&nbsp;bbb

How can I circumvent this and use character reference for HTML in R shiny when designing the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the string in `HTML()` to render it as HTML instead of plain text.

```
library(shiny)

tags$div(HTML("aaa&nbsp;bbb"))
```